# How to make dynamic collection view inside expendable table view cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have to make a screen with dynamic collection view inside a table view resizeable cell. When user tap on the button the cell will expand and show data inside collection view.

[image: As in following image there is a table with multiple content.]

[image: After clicking on Book button I have to show this type of collection view with dynamic content]

After clicking on Book button I have to show this type of collection view with dynamic content

Comment: can you help me for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73026269/bus-seat-view-design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a way to design this type of screen. I had to make collection view height dynamic, So I used following statement for that.

self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()

I want to refer following article to help them all who are facing the same issue or might be will face in future.

"https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-height-collection-views-dynamic-in-your-ios-apps-7d6ca94d2212/"

Comment: help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73026269/bus-seat-view-design

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question is broad. The simply I tried here to explain. please check:

Workaround would be like below

First you need to create a tableview cell which will show you listing of hotels.

Then you need to design the collection view inside the tableview cell that will show the timings.

Tableview height should be dynamic.
When you tap on tableview cell then the height should increase dynamically based on collectionview data count.

The overall structure should look like 
[image]

You can go through this link
https://medium.com/@gargankit476/multiple-collection-view-in-uitableview-ced7909a5af3

UPDATED:

In the tableview cell class you add your collection view outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

Inherit the delegate and datasource:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout { ..}
```

Set the CollectionView delegate and datasource like so in the tableview cell class as:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
  super.awakeFromNib()
  self.collectionView.delegate = self
  self.collectionView.dataSource = self
  //other stuff
}
```

Comment: I am doing exactly same, and when I am tapping on the cell. The cell is auto resizing, but did not get the collection view. I am calling collection view delegate and datasource in "didSelectRowAt indexPath" before reloading row.

Comment: Can you show your attempt please.
Show the collectionview datasource and respective code. and where you have put the collection view delegate datasource method?

Comment: Please see the updated answer. It seems your collection view delegate and datasource is not connected with the view. Please check that does your collection view method is getting called or not?
If it calls then please check for the datasource count whether it is empty or not?